# Date and Interval Addition in SparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute a simple SQL query on some dataframe in spark-shell the query adds interval of 1 week to some date as follows:

The original query:

```
scala> spark.sql("select Cast(table1.date2 as Date) + interval 1 week from table1").show()
```

Now when I did some tests:

```
scala> spark.sql("select Cast('1999-09-19' as Date) + interval 1 week from table1").show()
```

I got the results correctly

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CAST(CAST(CAST(1999-09-19 AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP) + interval 1 weeks AS DATE)|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                  1999-09-26|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(Just adding 7 days to 19 = 26)

But when I just changed the year to 1997 instead of 1999 the results changed!

```
scala> spark.sql("select Cast('1997-09-19' as Date) + interval 1 week from table1").show()

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CAST(CAST(CAST(1997-09-19 AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP) + interval 1 weeks AS DATE)|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                  1997-09-25|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why the reuslts changed? Shouldn't it be 26 not 25?

**So, is this a bug in sparkSQL related to some kind of itermediate calculations loss or I am missing something?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is probably a matter of conversions to local time. `INTERVAL` casts data to `TIMESTAMP` and then back to `DATE`:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT CAST('1997-09-19' AS DATE) + INTERVAL 1 weeks").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [10130 AS CAST(CAST(CAST(1997-09-19 AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP) + interval 1 weeks AS DATE)#19]
+- Scan OneRowRelation[]
```

(note the second and third `CASTs`) and Spark is known to be  [inconsequent when handling timestamps](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/SQL-TIMESTAMP-semantics-vs-SPARK-18350-tp21621.html).

`DATE_ADD` should exhibit more stable behavior:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT DATE_ADD(CAST('1997-09-19' AS DATE), 7)").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [10130 AS date_add(CAST(1997-09-19 AS DATE), 7)#27]
+- Scan OneRowRelation[]
```

Comment: Inconsistent too: If you have a cluster spanning two timezones, timestamp to date conversion completely falls apart (unless you use methods with explicit timezones every time).

Answer (score 3):

As of Spark 3, this bug has been fixed.  Let's create a DataFrame with the dates you mentioned and add a week interval.  Create the DataFrame.

```scala
import java.sql.Date

val df = Seq(
  (Date.valueOf("1999-09-19")),
  (Date.valueOf("1997-09-19"))
).toDF("some_date")
```

Add a week interval:

```scala
df
  .withColumn("plus_one_week", expr("some_date + INTERVAL 1 week"))
  .show()
```

```
+----------+-------------+
| some_date|plus_one_week|
+----------+-------------+
|1999-09-19|   1999-09-26|
|1997-09-19|   1997-09-26|
+----------+-------------+
```

You can also get this same result with the `make_interval()` SQL function:

```scala
df
  .withColumn("plus_one_week", expr("some_date + make_interval(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)"))
  .show()
```

We're working on [getting make_interval() exposed as Scala/PySpark functions](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/31073), so it's not necessary to use `expr` to access the function.

`date_add` only works for adding days, so it's limited.  `make_interval()` is a lot more powerful because it lets you add any combination of years / months / days / hours / minutes / seconds.

Comment: I can confirm that the function makeInterval is available and working with Datasets in spark 3.0.1 `makeInterval(years = 0, months = 0, weeks = 1, days = 0, hours = 0, mins = 0, secs = Decimal(0)) `